# Internal survey error in landing page

Tags: email, history-tracking

We are trying to view tracking for emails with survey, and when we submit, we recieve a landing page with the message "thank you for responding to our survey but we encountered an internal survey error. Please click on the button below to return to your email."
The tracking don´t appears. If we sent emails without survey, we can see tracking.
Do you know the reason of this?

Thank you

Comment: Is this something you have build, or a specific appExchange app that you have installed ? Having more insight in the technical background of this issue is most likely needed to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to contact the provider of the Managed Package if you are using an Appexchange Application. Else, you can check the Debug Logs for the current user and then see what exactly the error is.
The message which you are getting has been defined in the code itself.